# Using Alamofire and Codable for put request

Tags: json, swift, swift4, codable

I have a simple put request and I am using Alamofire's `Parameters` type to send data to the server. I would like to use codable. How do I either convert my codable struct to parameters or reconfigure the Alamofire request to take JSON objects as the parameter? What is the best and most efficient way to send post and put requests using Alamofire?

Here is what I am doing right now with Alamofire.

```
func addProduct(product:MainProduct, completionHandler:@escaping ((JSON?, Error?)->Void)) {

    let url = "INSERT_URL"

    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    ]

    var parameters:Parameters = [:]
    parameters["orderId"] = product.orderId
    parameters["orderSize"] = product.orderSize
    parameters["theOrderStatus"] = product.orderStatus
    let purchDate = Int((product.purchaseDate.timeIntervalSince1970)*1000)
    parameters["purchaseDate"] = purchDate
    parameters["archived"] = false

    Alamofire.request(url, method:.put, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers:headers).responseJSON {response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value):
            print ("finish")
            let swiftyJson = JSON(value)
            completionHandler(swiftyJson, nil)
        case .failure(let error):
            completionHandler(nil, error)
        }
    }
}
```

This is our struct.

```
struct MainProduct:Codable{

    var purchaseDate:Date
    var orderId:String
    var orderSize:Double
    var orderStatus:OrderStatus?

    var archived:Bool

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case purchaseDate
        case orderId
        case orderSize
        case orderStatus = "theOrderStatus"
        case archived
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you declaring most of your values as implicitly unwrapped optionals in `MainProduct`? It makes no sense.

Comment: so you are saying I should just get rid of the `!` right?

Comment: Indeed. You shouldn't use implicitly unwrapped optional unless you have a very good reason to do so, since they can easily lead to errors when not used correctly.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks! Do you know how to to encode the struct?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can make a new `URLRequest` and set `httpBody` to your encoded `jsonData`. Try this code...

```
func addProduct(product: MainProduct, completionHandler: @escaping ((JSON?, Error?)->Void)) {

    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    let jsonData = try! encoder.encode(product)

    let url = "INSERT_URL"

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = HTTPMethod.put.rawValue
    request.setValue("application/json; charset=UTF-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.httpBody = jsonData

    Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value):
            print ("finish")
            let swiftyJson = JSON(value)
            completionHandler(swiftyJson, nil)
        case .failure(let error):
            completionHandler(nil, error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the hell is this not possible with Alamofire out of the box? It's 2023... Thanks for sharing this!