# POST JSON Object through Almofire throws error

Tags: json, swift, post

> Error: Extra argument in call

```
let parameters = [
        "foo": [1,2,3],
        "bar": [
            "baz": "qux"
        ]
    ]
    Alamofire.request(.POST, "https://httpbin.org/post", parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON)
```

[image]

Comment: try this code `let parameters = [
        "foo": [1,2,3],
        "bar": [
            "baz": "qux"
        ]
    ] as! [String: Any]`

Comment: Are you sure you do not want to do this with an `Encodable` parameter object? It is a lot less messy to handle, especially upon decoding, but that would probably be another question.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47685241/using-alamofire-and-codable-for-put-request) shows how to make a request from a JSONEncoder-encoded `Codable` using Alamofire. I would consider this more predictable than letting it encode "something" as `.JSON` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For heterogeneous type dictionaries you need to provide annotation explicitly, in your case it would be `[String: Any]`.

```
    let parameters: [String: Any] = [
            "foo": [1,2,3],
            "bar": [
                "baz": "qux"
            ]
        ]
```

For alamofire request I think Either you are using the old version of alamofire or you written the method incorrectly. Using `Alamofire 4.0`, it will be written as:

```
    Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/post", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding())
```

or you can `JSONEncoding.default` as encoding as well:

```
    Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/post", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
```