# How to Post Objects Array without a Key in Alamofire using Struct Encodable, iOS, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, http-post, alamofire

**I want to post following body via `Alamofire`. this is the exact post body. I have tested this with postman**

```
[
   {
      "keyone":{
         "name":"abc",
         "value":"1"
      },
      "keytwo":{
         "age":"23",
         "id":"9812fvereaere112"
      },
      "keythree":{
         "expired":true,
         "freshuser":false
      },
      "keyfour":{
         "license":true
      }
   }
]
```

---

**I have created a `Struct` for this.**

```
// MARK: - Keyfour
struct Keyfour: Codable {
    let license: Bool
}

// MARK: - Keyone
struct Keyone: Codable {
    let name, value: String
}

// MARK: - Keythree
struct Keythree: Codable {
    let expired, freshuser: Bool
}

// MARK: - Keytwo
struct Keytwo: Codable {
    let age, id: String
}
```

> And then I created an array from these objects and try to use it as the
>   parameter of Alamofire.but `Alamofire` requires `[String: Any]` but I should send
>   `[Dictionary<String, Any>]`. how can I do that.

**I tried to convert my Object Array to dictionary but it fails with below method**

```
 private func convertdocprocesstoDictonary(jsonstring: String) -> Dictionary<String, Any>? {
        if let data = jsonstring.data(using: .utf8) {
            do {
                return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? Dictionary<String, Any>
            } catch let jsonerr {
                print("\(jsonerr.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

// Tried this with [Dictionary<String, Any>] as well.it fails too


let jdat = try JSONEncoder().encode(Array_of_Objects)
let jstring = String(data: jdat, encoding: .utf8)
let dic = convertdocprocesstoDictonary(jsonstring: jstring)
```

and then attached dic as the parameters. nothing succeeded. hope your help with this. have a nice day and be safe.

Comment: Converting Array to Dictionary doesn't make sense. Passing through JSON inbetween doesn't make sense either. There are plenty of question about how send an Array with Alamofire. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47685241/using-alamofire-and-codable-for-put-request?